# Calculating an expected value of a sum of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I'm trying to see that I have understand the expected value definition correctly. However, I think that my intuition in the following exercise is wrong.

**Definitions**:

We define a set of $n$ jobs and $m$ machines, where each of the jobs is denoted by $W_j$ and takes $0 \leq W_j \leq 1$ seconds.
The assignment of the jobs is random.

We denote ${M_i}_j$ as the $j$ th job that was assigned, and ${M_i}_j$ = $W_j$. If $j$ wasn't assigned to the $M$ machine, ${M_i}_j$ = 0.

Also, we define ${M_i}$ = $\sum_{j=1}^n{M_i}_j$ (the sum of seconds that it will take the machine to run the jobs).

How do I calculate the expected value of $E[{M_i}]$?

**My proposed solution:**

Using the definition of expected value and ${M_i}$:

$E[{M_i}]={\frac 1m}\sum_{j=1}^n{M_i}_j$ $={\frac {M_i}m}$

I'm using ${\frac 1m}$ because the probability of each ${W_j}$ to be assigned to some machine ${M_i}$ is the same (since its random). I even did some tests using python to check my intuition, and it seems that it is ${\frac 1m}$.

Answer (score 1):

The expected Wj is (.5) and with any combination of machines, the total machine time is n(.5) and dividing by m machines, E[Mi] = (1/m)(n)(.5)
For Expected Total Run Time, you would break each n,m scenario into combinations, multiplying each way by the maximum jobs on any one machine, and dividing by total combinations, then  summing (left for others to formulize, good luck).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I didn't understand your answer. What do you mean by (.5)? you mean 1/2? Regarding the expected total run time - could you please elaborate more? I'm not sure what is each combination.

Comment: Yes, .5 is 1/2 (seconds). The expected total time is based on the maximum jobs for one machine, while the others may sit idle. If n=3, m=4, then one machine could work for 1.5 seconds (total time for all jobs). There are 4 machines, so 4 ways it could happen. Divide by possible combinations (14), to account for expectation. 6 ways to have a machine get 2 jobs (1 second), and 4 ways to have at most one job per machine (they are all done in .5 seconds (expected). That's just one n,m scenario, so a formula would take more effort than this.

Comment: Thanks for the useful example. Still, there is one thing that I'm missing - the last jump here from -  $E[{M_i}] = \sum_{j=1}^{n}{{M_i}_j}\mathbb P(W_j|M_i)$ = ${\frac 1m}E[\sum_{j=1}^{n}{{M_i}_j}]$
=${\frac n{2m}}$ How do you "know" that the expected value of Mij for all j, is n/2?

Comment: The 1/2 I got was the mean time for each job (1-0)/2=1/2 seconds.

Comment: I meant to say (1+0)/2=  1/2.